# How can i convert the trained model (yolov4-obj_best) into Pytorch (i.e.) from Darknet to Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, nvidia, onnx, darknet, tensorrt

```
C:\Users\FHW>python demo_darknet2onnx.py yolov4-obj obj yolov4-obj_best train 64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FHW\demo_darknet2onnx.py", line 5, in <module>
    "execution_count": null,
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

Currently I am using `CUDA 11.2`, `CuDNN 11.2(v8.1.0.77)`, `OpenCV 4.5.2`, `Cmake 3.19.6` and `Python (3.10.9)` from **Anaconda environment**. I am currently working on a Custom data object detection project using **Yolov4 Darknet**. After successfully completing the training of the model, I want to convert the trained model (**yolov4-obj_bes**t) into **Pytorch** (i.e.) from **Darknet** to **Pytorch**. so that I can convert the **Pytorch** model to the **onnx model** to do the inferencing with **TensorRT**.

I tried this repository  `https://github.com/Tianxiaomo/pytorch-YOLOv4` using the command:

```
pip install onnxruntime
python demo_darknet2onnx.py <cfgFile> <namesFile> <weightFile> <imageFile> <batchSize>

Executed command:
pip install onnxruntime
python demo_darknet2onnx.py yolov4-obj obj yolov4-obj_best train 64

yolov4-obj      = <cfgFile> denotes the cfg file where the custom configuration changes are made
obj             = <namesFile> denotes the name of two classes (i.e) weed and carrot
yolov4-obj_best = <weightFile> weights obtained after the training
train           = <imageFile> Here the image is in .txt form which contains the path of the images
64              = <batchSize>
```

After executing this command:

```
python demo_darknet2onnx.py yolov4-obj obj yolov4-obj_best train 64
```

in the Command prompt I am facing the following error which I have attached to the image above. I have also changed the `execution count`: from **null** to **none**.

How can I solve this error?

Can someone provide me with a solution?

Or can anyone give me another method to change my Darknet weights to ONNX or Pytorch?

Comment: No way. I'm using this approach to running darknet models on TensorRT: https://github.com/enazoe/yolo-tensorrt